# Multiprocessing: Order of Execution

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying the following code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):    
    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)
    print(p.map(f, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13]))
```

As I understand the 5 processors get `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` to perform operations on. If processor 1 finishes it's job, does it get `5` right away while rest processors are busy with `1,2,3,4` or does the code finish for all processors so that next batch will all together get `5, 6, 7, 8, 9` and so on. If the later happens how do I implement the above code so that moment a processors goes idle it gets new job assigned to it?

How do I test the implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Threadpool spawns a new thread immediately (adding to your example). Notice how thread 4 took long enough that that the 12th task is able to start.

PS I just noticed you forgot 10.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import random

def f(x):
    print "Enter %s" % x
    time.sleep( random.randrange(1,100,1)/10.0 )
    print "Exit %s" % x
    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)
    print(p.map(f, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13]))

Enter 0
Enter 1
Enter 2
Enter 3
Enter 4
Exit 0
Enter 5
Exit 3
Enter 6
Exit 2
Enter 7
Exit 5
Enter 8
Exit 1
Enter 9
Exit 6
Enter 11
Exit 11
Enter 12
Exit 4
Enter 13
Exit 7
Exit 12
Exit 9
Exit 8
Exit 13
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, this situation is possible.** The input is partitioned into separate tasks first. The issue comes about when the tasks are unequally sized (in terms of processing time) and there are too few of them to fill in the gaps.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map):

> **map**(*func*, *iterable*[, *chunksize*])
>
> This method chops the iterable into a number of chunks which it submits to the process pool as separate tasks. The (approximate) size
>   of these chunks can be specified by setting chunksize to a positive
>   integer.

### Example

To illustrate this behavior I changed `f(x)` so it takes `x` seconds to complete.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import threading

def f(x):
    print('x: ' + str(x) + '\tThread ID: ' + str(threading.get_ident()))
    time.sleep(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    chunksize = 3
    with Pool(2) as p:
        p.map(f, [10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], chunksize)
```

The input array `[10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` is partitioned into `len(arr) / chunksize = 2` groups:

```
[10, 1, 1]  # For thread 1, takes 12 seconds to finish
[ 1, 1, 1]  # For thread 2, takes 3 seconds to finish
```

So, thread 2 will finish after 3 seconds, while thread 1 will continue working for another 9 seconds.

Example output:

```
x: 10   Thread ID: 8556
x: 1    Thread ID: 59180
x: 1    Thread ID: 59180
x: 1    Thread ID: 59180
x: 1    Thread ID: 8556
x: 1    Thread ID: 8556
```

If you find yourself in this situation, then you can force a smaller `chunksize`. A value of 1 ensures as balanced a workload as possible, at the cost of higher overhead.

Comment: I feel you have something important to share about this thread pool, but, the example with all the "1" make it difficult to track.

Comment: I actually used the 1's to simplify the example. :/ In this example the work will be split so thread 1 will take 12 seconds, and thread 2 takes 3 seconds.